# Navigate to a third party URL without making it available in location values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to redirect my application to a payment gateway URL but after successful authorisation, I don't want to navigate back to the payment gateway URL when I run window.location.back()

Is there any way to do the same in JS?

Comment: You can pop a new window or if you have access to the gateway, use location.replace() instead of changing url

Comment: @mplungjan I tried with location.replace but doesn't that replace the current URL with the given URL? It was not working with location.replace.
And I am sorry but according to my requirement, I cannot open the URL in a new window. It has to be in the same window.

Comment: `<a href="paymentgatewayauth" onclick="location.replace(this.href); return false">Click</a>` will replace the current URL with a new url and remove the page the link is on from the history

Comment: @mplungjan
Hi, I am using `window.open(this.redirectUrl, "_self");` for redirection to the payment gateway.
if I use `location.replace(this.redirectUrl)` instead, It still gives me the payment gateway on back. Can you please let me know if I am I missing anything?

Comment: If you use window open then you only need location.replace if you have ANOTHER link in the popup

Comment: @mplungjan Yes my pop up has another link. Its the link for a third party gateway. I tried using `location.replace(this.redirectUrl)` instead of window.open and this.redirectUrl was still avaialble in my history

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226349/discussion-between-anusrees-and-mplungjan).